# mask for comma separated numbers list

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to creat a mask for comma separated values for my inputs, but I'm having dificulties.

Can you guys help me?

Here is my current mask:

```
<script>
    $(document).on("keyup keydown keypress", "commaseparated", function (e) {
        if (!$(this).val().match(/^([0-9]{0,1})(,[0-9]{1,}){1,}?$/g)) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
<input type="text" class="commaseparated" />
<!-- example input would be
     1235 <- single number
     or
     2654,524874,5456 <- many numbers
-->
```

Thanks in advance :)

**EDIT**
Well, this is not exactly a mask. What I want is that the user can only insert numbers and commas, e.g:

```
123 -> allowed
123,123 -> allowed
123,, -> not allowed
123,letters -> not allowed
```

Comment: What is expected result ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, give a try to the below jquery.

```
//We need to capture the keypress event, as this is triggered before the value is displayed in the text box.
$(document).on("keypress", ".commaseparated", function (e) {
    var currentValue = $(this).val();
    //If the value is empty, let user enter numerals.
    if(currentValue == "" && e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) {
        return true;
    }
    else {
        //If some value is there, get the last character.
        var lastChar = currentValue.substr(currentValue.length - 1);

        //If the last character is comma, let user enter numerals.
        if(lastChar == "," && e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57){
            return true;
        }
        //If the last character is comma, deny entering comma again. 
        else if(lastChar == "," && e.keyCode == 44){
            return false;
        }
        //If the control reaches here and as last character could only be numeral, let user enter only comma or numerals. 
        else if (e.keyCode == 44 || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57)) {
            return true;
        }
        // for everything else, return false. 
        else{
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Find the jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bfjzkcas/).

Comment: interesting. Can you put some comments in the code in order to explain it better?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `RegExp` `/(,|\D)(?=\1)|^[,\D]|[^,\d]$/g` to match comma or non-digit character followed by comma or non-digit character or comma or non-digit at beginning of string or last character of string is not a digit or comma, replace match with empty string.

```js
$(".commaseparated").on("input", function(e) {
  $(e.target).prop("value", function(_, val) {
    return val.replace(/(,|\D)(?=\1)|^[,\D]|[^,\d]$/g, "");
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<input type="text" class="commaseparated"/>
```

Comment: This doesn't work because `|` doesn't mean 'or' in a character set, thus the regex allows characters `{`, `}`, and `|` to be entered. This can be verified in the code snippet. Unfortunately I'm not regex-smart enough to figure out the correct regex.

Comment: Oops, I left out `+` from the list of characters mistakenly allowed in my comment above...discovering my omission 2 minutes after SO's cutoff for editing comments  :/

Comment: Should the regex end with `$`?  With the `$` I can type a non-digit in the middle of the string (but not at the end). If I remove the `$` then I'm prevented from entering a non-digit anywhere. Either way, thank you for updating your answer 2 years after you wrote it.  I learned more about regex thanks to your edit.

Comment: @Paul _"I can type a non-digit in the middle of the string"_ Not able to enter a character that is not a digit or not a comma here.

Comment: Hmm, maybe it's my browser (FF 52). I typed `1,2,3` then used the arrow key to move the cursor between `2` and `,`. I typed `a` then moved the cursor to the end of the text and continued to type numbers and commas.  Nevertheless, that's an edge case and we do back-end validation...your answer is great and remains very helpful!